# Reusable Pentaho dashboard side-bar

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-cde

I have added a side bar like this one onto a CDE dashboard.

https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/responsive-navigation-menu

Now the sidebar needs to be on every page listed on the menu.

What is the best way to go about this?

- I could copy it on every single dash board - it works but it's not great especially if I need to change stg ex-post.
- Create an "index" page with the side bar and an iframe to display the "sub" dashboards?
- Create a widget (I tried but no success so far)
- Custom component?

Answer (score 1):

I think I solved the problem by using jquery load like these guys did.

[Include another HTML file in a HTML file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8988855/include-another-html-file-in-a-html-file)